# C2041 Illegal Digit for base 8 error preventing program from compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

Hello I'm a college student and I'm using Visual Studios 2022 for my C++ class,

I was doing a project and I couldn't debug it. This is what it shows when I press f5:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: the oint is that you cant debug a program until it compiles cleanly. Fix the error that others have (and the compiler) have told you about (although its not obvious)

Comment: Numbers starting with a `0` are considered octal (base 8), and can then only contain digits 0-7.

Answer (score 1):

Remove zero from the beginning of `const int STUDENT_ID = 0488319`

Comment: If you need to actually store leading zeros you can't use an int.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You have to use some sort of an array to store all digits of a number including leading zeros.